# How can i use redis with mongoose and node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, redis

I have a simple get method which returns all users from my mongodb.
Also i've connected redis. 
And now i need to use redis caching mechanism to make it faster.
How can i set and get data from cache using redis and just in case there is nothing in cache, get data from mongodb ?

```
app.js 

const usersRoute = require("./routes/users");
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();

app.use("/users", usersRoute);

client.on("connect", () => console.log("Redis client connected!"));
client.on("error", err => {
  console.log(`Error ${err}`);
});


User.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);


users.js

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const users = await User.find();
  res.send(users);
});
```